# Killing process cmd.exe ping.exe and conhost.exe

Tags: vb.net, cmd, ping

I have question regarding killing process. Below are my codes in VB language.
I can't seems to kill ping.exe and conhost.exe and i am only able to kill 1 cmd.exe even if 70 cmd is created.
Thank you

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim xl As Integer = 368
    Dim value As Integer = 0
    For value = 0 To 69
        Proc.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe")
        Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = ("cmd.exe /k" + TextBox1.Text + " " + ipAdd.Text + " " + TextBox2.Text + " " + TextBox3.Text)
        Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
        Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        Proc.Start()
    Next
    Timer1.Enabled = False

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Proc.Kill()
    Proc.Close()
    'Proc.Start("cmd.exe", "/C choice /C Y /N /T 3 & Del " + Application.ExecutablePath)
    'Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident that you want to kill all the cmd processes, you could try:

```
    For Each proc As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd")
        proc.Kill()
    Next
```

The problem with the code above is that Proc only refers to the last process instance created in the For Next loop.